# How to locally change aboverulesep (booktabs)?

Tags: booktabs

I know how to change it globally by adding `\setlength\aboverulesep{10pt}` in the preamble of my tex file, but how to change it just for a given table?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l}
a \\
\midrule
b \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

How to locally change the value of `\aboverulesep` in the above MWE?

Comment: just move the command to the line between `\begin{table}` and `\begin{tabular}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

`\setlength` is a local setting, it just appears to be global if you use it in the preamble just as it isn't in any group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\aboverulesep{10pt}
\begin{tabular}{l}
a \\
\midrule
b \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\setlength\aboverulesep{30pt}
\begin{tabular}{l}
a \\
\midrule
b \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\setlength\aboverulesep{100pt}
\begin{tabular}{l}
a \\
\midrule
b \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```